# How to achieve this query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am new in mongodb, my mysql query is:

```
select count(_id) as numberOfRecord,createdDate,orderId 
from CakeOrder 
where createdDate >= '2019-08-12' and createdDate <= '2019-10-12'
group by createdDate
order by createdDate desc
```

How I will convert this query to mongodb?

Date format is `"createdDate" : ISODate("2019-10-12T07:12:36.390Z")`

Comment: select count(_id) as numberOfRecord,createdDate,orderId 
from CakeOrder 
where createdDate >= '2019-08-12' and createdDate <= '2019-10-12'
group by (createdDate)
order by createdDate desc

Comment: Please share array and what do you want data ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [MongoDB Aggregation Framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

here is mongo shell command for you:

```
db.getCollection("myCollection").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "createDate" : {
                            "$gte" : ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        "createDate" : {
                            "$lte" : ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "$createDate", 
                "count" : {
                    "$sum" : 1
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$sort" : {
                "_id" : -1
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Comment: I want to select only some columns from table

Comment: @Sayeed you can improve $group section as you wish. Here is detailed doc. for group aggregation pipeline https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/.  this is the only way